# D/AbsListView: Get MotionRecognitionManager when ListView is ran using a Samsung S7 Device

Tags: java, android, listview, android-studio-2.1

I'm using my Samsung S7 to develop an Android application where I want to display a list of products I aim to search through within a ListFragment class. I have developed a custom adaptor class to facilitate this. Unfortunately I get this strange response to using the custom adaptor (and ArrayAdaptor as well) when I run it on my Samsung phone:

08-01 22:18:11.112 29717-29717/com.alappin.dailyderma D/AbsListView: Get MotionRecognitionManager

08-01 22:18:11.112 29717-29717/com.alappin.dailyderma E/MotionRecognitionManager: mSContextService = android.hardware.scontext.ISContextService$Stub$Proxy@4ad43d8

08-01 22:18:11.112 29717-29717/com.alappin.dailyderma E/MotionRecognitionManager: motionService = com.samsung.android.motion.IMotionRecognitionService$Stub$Proxy@981e331

08-01 22:18:11.112 29717-29717/com.alappin.dailyderma E/MotionRecognitionManager: motionService = com.samsung.android.motion.IMotionRecognitionService$Stub$Proxy@981e331

The app doesn't crash but it doesn't display anything. However, when I ran the app on two different Genymotion emulaters, the listview executed as designed.

I'm really stumped on how to troubleshoot this device specific problem. I also do not understand the error or the relevance motion recognition has to a listview. I've tried searching relentlessly for a similar problem but with no luck.

Here is my code for the ListFragment:

```
public class ProductFragment extends ListFragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

List<Product> products;

public ProductFragment() {

}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_product, container, false);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Item: " + i, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    products = new ArrayList<>();
    products.add(new Product("P1 barcode", "P1 title", "P1 brand", "P1 ingredients"));
    products.add(new Product("P2 barcode", "P2 title", "P2 brand", "P2 ingredients"));

    for (int i = 0; i < products.size() ; i++) {
        Log.i(DEBUG + " products", products.get(i).getTitle());
    }

    ProductArrayAdapter adapter = new ProductArrayAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.product_listitem, products);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this);
}
}
```

Here is my code for the custom adaptor class:

```
public class ProductArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Product> {

private Context context;
private List<Product> objects;


public ProductArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Product> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    this.context = context;
    this.objects = objects;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Product product = objects.get(position);

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.product_listitem, null);

    TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.product_name_tv);
    name.setText(product.getTitle());

    return view;
}
}
```

product_fragment.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:orientation="vertical"
         tools:context="com.alappin.dailyderma.fragments.ProductFragment">

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>

<TextView
    android:id="@android:id/empty"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

product_listitem.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/product_name_tv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="placeholder"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```